# Wrong answer was accepted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, accepted-answer

What is the procedure to let the OP know that he/she has accepted a wrong answer ? The answer in question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031838/inheriting-instance-variables-in-actionscript/16031949#16031949).

Comment: You can leave a comment?

Comment: But what about the people who will refer to that answer in future ? Can't the moderators edit that answer or let the person know to correct it ?

Comment: Other than leaving a comment, nope. Acceptance is up to the OP only.

Comment: P.s. Slightly off-topic, but please learn how to use markdown. There is no need for the HTML in your posts.

Comment: Leave a comment and downvote the incorrect answer. Moderators don't (generally?) deal with the factual accuracy of answers since they can't be expected to be an expert on everything.